# Exporting an Access subform to Word using VBA

Tags: ms-access, ms-word, vba

I have a main form with details such as order number, customer name, address, contact. This main form contains a subform, which holds the items of that specific order number which links the main form.

I need to export both the main form data and subform data to word. I am using the following code to send data from the main form using bookmarks to word. I am unable and unsure how to do this with the subform data.

Thanks

```
'This array contains the placeholders in the MS Word template
docVars = Array("<company>", "<att>", "<date>", "<ref>", "<project>", "<Insert scope here>")

'This array contains the MS Access variables
accessVars = Array(CustomerName, CustomerAttn, OrderDate, OrderNo, Project, Notes)

'error checking --- do arrays have the same number of elements?
If (UBound(docVars) = UBound(accessVars)) Then
    If (IsNull(accessVars(1)) Or IsNull(accessVars(4))) Then
        MsgBox ("Project or Att field cannot be empty!!!")
    Else
        Set objWord = CreateObject("Word.Application")
        Set quoteDoc = objWord.Documents.Add(Template:="C:\folder\OrderTemplate.dotx", NewTemplate:=False, DocumentType:=0)

        For i = 0 To (UBound(docVars))
            With quoteDoc.Application.selection.Find
                .Text = docVars(i)
                .Replacement.Text = Left(accessVars(i), 254)
                .Forward = True
                .Wrap = wdFindContinue
                .Format = False
                .MatchCase = False
                .MatchWholeWord = False
                .MatchWildcards = False
                .MatchSoundsLike = False
                .MatchAllWordForms = False
            End With

        quoteDoc.Application.selection.Find.Execute Replace:=2
        Next i
        quoteDoc.Application.Visible = True
    End If
```

Comment: What you don't show is how you get the `accessVars`. You should get the subform data (order lines) in the same way, only will you loop through the sub form lines or query results. Then you insert them in Word and apply formatting. As the numbe of lines will be variable, you cannot use `Find` but you could insert a tabe after the order base data.

Comment: AccessVars are the fields on my main form where this code is executed from. They are the fields of my Order table.

Comment: Curious, why even go this approach? Unless you do not have MS Access the program, Access comes equipped with a report engine using table/query recordsources for document output.

Comment: Is your question is basically: "How do I transfer the "many" side of the one-to-many data to Word and format it?" Most often, the best way to display the data is a *table*, and the most efficient way to create a table is to put the data into a character-delimited string, assign that to the target Range in Word, then use ConvertToTable to turn it into a table...

Comment: @CindyMeister sorry for the late reponse, that is basically what I'm trying to do. Have not used those methods before but will look into it.

Comment: In that case, this article might help you get started: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa537149%28v=office.11%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396